# Handling /_ah/start and /_ah/stop requests on App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, app.yaml

How should I handle `/_ah/start` and `/_ah/stop` requests? Right now they're just getting 404s.

Also, why is it that sometimes the start and stop are 10 minutes apart and sometimes 1 minute apart?

`app.yaml` looks like this:

```js
instance_class: B4_1G
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 60m
```

[App Engine logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg7R6.png)

Comment: Are you using Standard or Flex environment?

Comment: Standard environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your requests with, using Express, something like

`app.get('/_ah/start', (req, res) => { //rest of the code`

As for the why the difference in time between the requests, it depends on the usage of your app. You receive requests to `/_ah/start` [when there is the need to start a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#startup), and to `/_ah/stop` for restarting/stopping